# Cannot convert vector of different formats to POSIXct

Tags: r, posixct

I have a dataset containing a date in CHAR format that I want to convert to POSIXct. The dates are always in one of five formats, but for this example two will suffice:

```
test <- c("15/03/19 17:16", "15/03/19,17:16", "15/03/19,17:16")
formats <- c(
    "%d/%m/%y,%H:%M",
    "%d/%m/%y %H:%M",
    "%d/%m/%Y,%H:%M",
    "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",
    "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
)

as.POSIXct(test[1], tz = "GMT", tryFormats = formats) # works
as.POSIXct(test[2:3], tz = "GMT", tryFormats = formats) # works
as.POSIXct(test, tz = "GMT", tryFormats = formats)    # fails
```

Individually, the two dates convert without issue. When the vector (or in my case, the datatable via `mutate`) is put through `as.POSIXct` the following error is generated:

> Error in as.POSIXct.character(x, tz, ...) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Presumably `as.POSIXct` is picking only one of the formats in tryFormat and trying to apply that to the whole set, which won't work.

Is my only option here creating a blank column and manually looping through each individual row to populate it?

Example dates:

```
15/03/19 17:16
15/03/19,17:16
15/03/2019 17:16
15/03/2019,17:16
20190315171600GS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `lubridate::dmy_hm` which works for both. Also your `formats` needs correction I believe.

```
formats <- c("%d/%m/%y,%H:%M", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")

lubridate::dmy_hm(test)
#[1] "2019-03-15 17:16:00 UTC" "2019-03-15 17:16:00 UTC" "2019-03-15 17:16:00 UTC"
```

Or with `anytime`

```
anytime::addFormats(formats)
anytime::anytime(test)
```

---

If we need to specify formats explicitly, we may also use `parse_date_time`

```
lubridate::parse_date_time(test, formats)
```

Comment: Need to be able to specify the formats because one is a little obscure, eg `20181130223406GS` which is formatted `"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`. I removed all the existing formats in anytime and added just the five I have, but it's still parsing wrong. Interestingly the other dates also come up as 18:16, but that is likely a setting somewhere.

Comment: @Deadly-Bagel Can you check the update with `parse_date_time`. Also I think you need `%y` instead of `%Y` in your `formats` since it is only 2 digit year.

Comment: Some are two digits and some are four digits, between that and the comma it accounts for four of the formats (added example of each to question). Yes, the parse_date_time does indeed do the trick, overlooked that somehow. Thanks!